# Struts2 performance

Tags: java, struts2

I'm converting a `Struts1` application to `Struts2`. As a beginning I only ported a few of the actions to see how they behave in `Struts2`. One of these actions serves an Ajax request sent by the clients once every second. In the current `Struts1` implementation the request takes about 10-15 ms to execute, which I can see with Firebug. The `Struts2` version now takes over 250 ms. I added the profiling interceptor to the action and I can see that most of this time is spent in setting up the execution of the action. The time spent in the interceptors is negligible.

Is it expected?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follwing the steps,

1. Turn off development mode using struts.dev="false";
2. Create your own default interceptorStack which specific to your project and remove  unneccesary interceptors you are not using.
3. For further information refer the following link [struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/performance-tuning.html](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/performance-tuning.html)
4. And you can find action execution time using timer interceptor so called timer.
5. And also i tried with JSTL, OGNL tags to compare the performance of jsp page rendering time. In my case OGNL has given best performance.

Comment: The "struts.dev=false" did it. I'm now back to the timings I had before with Struts1. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are different aspects of benchmarking an application for the performance.The one mentioned by you seems very alarming as the difference is somewhat 25x.
Not sure what you mean by setting up the execution of the Action? so its really a bit hard to suggest any thing is particular.
We have like 9-10 S2 application and none of them have any performance issue as of now.

My suggestion is to use some profiling tool and get th information which specific block is causing an application to get slow, beside you can always follow the tips as suggest in other answer.

Which version of S2 are you using?

Comment: Here's what I meant by "setting up the execution of the action". From the profiling interceptor: `[0ms] - create DefaultActionProxy: [0ms] - actionCreate: currenttime [359ms] - invoke:  [359ms] - interceptor: exception...` All the execution time is spent in the creation action.

Comment: @D.Laroche: Your problem i believe already solved since S2 when in dev mode tend to reload  every configuration and other things for each request